# Recover DB password stored in my DBeaver connection

Tags: dbeaver

I forgot the password of a dev instance (irresponsible.. yeah, I am working on it). I have the connection saved in my DBeaver with the password. I am still able to connect using that connection. DBeaver is not showing it in plain text. Is there anyway I can retrieve the password? Asking DBA to reset the password is the last resort. I tried to copy paste to a notepad, copying is disabled apparently.

Comment: this work for me: https://bugdays.com/dbeaver-password-decrypter

Comment: This question is for a tool used often by programmers, it happens to also be used by other people LOL.  SU might work too, but I think it's fine here since the answer is practically a programming one.

Comment: @rogerdpack DBeaver may be used often by programmers, that does not make it a tool which is **primarily** used by programmers. It is also used by DBAs, or other people querying databases.

Comment: On Windows, this works: 

`openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in "%AppData%\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver\credentials-config.json"`. You can download openssl on windows here - https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: On Mac, this works:
`openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in ~/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json`

Answer (score 256, accepted):

### For newer DBeaver ( 6.1.3+ )

The credential file is located `~/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json` (I was on Mac). I put together a javascript function here https://www.bugdays.com/dbeaver-password-decrypter to decrypt it. Go there and select credentials-config.json file, bugdays will decrypt it and display it. Its purely within client side, there is no server uploading (However its a risky practice)

### Pre- DBeaver 6.1.3

Follow these steps (My DBeaver version was 3.5.8 and it was on Mac OsX El Capitan)

1. Locate the file in which DBeaver stores the connection details. For
   me, it was in this location
   `~/.dbeaver/General/.dbeaver-data-sources.xml`. This file is hidden,
   so keep that in mind when you look for it.
2. Locate your interested Datasource Definition node in that file.
3. **Decrypt the password:** Unfortunately, everything is in plain text except password; Password is in some kind of Encrypted form. Decrypt it to plain-text using this [tool](https://bugdays.com/dbeaver-password-decrypter).

## Original Answer

I put together a quick and dirty [Java program](https://github.com/so-random-dude/oneoffcodes/blob/master/SimpleStringEncrypter.java) by copying core of DBeaver's method for decrypting the password.  Once you have the Encrypted password string, just execute this program, it will convert the password to plain text and prints it

## How to run it

On Line Number 13, just replace `OwEKLE4jpQ==` with whatever encrypted password you are finding in `.dbeaver-data-sources.xml` file for your interested datasource. Compile it and run it, it will print the plain-text password.

https://github.com/jaisonpjohn/dbeaver-password-retriever/blob/master/SimpleStringEncrypter.java

Apparently, this is a "Popular" mistake. So I have deployed an AWS lambda function with the aforementioned code. Use this at your own risk, you will never know whether I am logging your password or not

```
curl https://lmqm83ysii.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/dbeaver-password-decrypter \
-X POST --data "OwEKLE4jpQ=="
```

Even better, here is the UI https://bugdays.com/dbeaver-password-decrypter. This goes without saying, use this at your own risk

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with the following steps, but it's not working.
I edited the program to include the encrypted string from the file. I complied the program with `javac SimpleStringEncrypter.java`. Then trying to run it with `javac SimpleStringEncrypter` I receive the error `Could not find or load main class`

Comment: @Oranges13 That's a weird issue and I think it has nothing to do with this program. I would suggest you to compile and run a helloworld program successfully, and then replace that program's content with the above given file and re-compile it and run it.

Comment: I had to comment out the namespace in the file for it to work effectively.

Comment: @Oranges13 namespace? you meant the package name? Thanks, I removed that from the code

Comment: I created an equivalent python script using your code as reference: https://gist.github.com/felipou/f5472ad5f6a414528b44beb102e17fb4
It was faster than it would take me to install the java compiler :)

Comment: @felipou Nice, thanks for sharing
If you dont want to run any program, just use this UI - http://dbeaver-password-decrypter.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Comment: @felipou Your solution is great and you should post it as an answer.

Comment: MUST have link [http://dbeaver-password-decrypter.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com](http://dbeaver-password-decrypter.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com)

Comment: I prefer @felipou version as it's run client-side, where so-random-dude is sending the password to a server out of my control. Thank you to both though.

Comment: Since version 6.1.3, this no longer works.  The credentials are now stored encrypted in `.dbeaver/credentials-config.json` according to this: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Admin-Manage-Connections.  I'm assuming this is an encrypted json file (it's not plaintext json).

Comment: With version Version: 6.0.3.201904211926, the cred file is `~/.dbeaver4/General/.dbeaver-data-sources.xml`

Comment: Here is a newer version, based on @rogerdpack answer https://gist.github.com/felipou/50b60309f99b70b1e28f6d22da5d8e61

Comment: for win, the path is `C:\Users\<YOURUSER>\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver`

Comment: @felipou I can confirm that [the gist you linked](https://gist.github.com/felipou/50b60309f99b70b1e28f6d22da5d8e61) works for the newer versions of DBeaver. (version 21.1.5, in my case)

Comment: You absolute legend !!! Thank you!

Answer (score 244):

This can be done with OpenSSL:

```sh
openssl aes-128-cbc -d \
  -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a \
  -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 \
  -in credentials-config.json | \
  dd bs=1 skip=16 2>/dev/null
```

Example for macOS in one line:

```sh
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in "${HOME}/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json" | dd bs=1 skip=16 2>/dev/null
```

For Linux, change the above path to `~/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json`.

The key is from [the source](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/blob/d69a75e63bf0a00e37f6b4ab9c9aa4fcaa0ded23/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.model/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/model/impl/app/DefaultSecureStorage.java#L32) and is converted to hexadecimal. This can be done in Python:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<16b', -70, -69, 74, -97, 119, 74, -72, 83, -55, 108, 45, 101, 61, -2, 84, 74).hex()
'babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a'
```

Edit: I've published [the script for this here](https://github.com/Tatsh/dbeaver-creds/blob/master/dbeaver-creds).

Comment: Works with new 21+:

In fact, tested with: Versión 21.0.3.202104181339

Comment: Works great with Windows version of dbeaver, I just ran it in WSL2.

Comment: Still works in version 22 (22.0.1.202203181646) installed from rpm package.

Comment: Working on DBeaver 21.3. Saved my life :D Thanks

Comment: 21.0.0 windows  I get "bad decrypt
9776:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:./crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:468:"
Same in command prompt & wsl2

Comment: If this tells you the file doesn't exist, or you don't see the credential you're looking for, back up to the `workspace6` directory and see if maybe you've defined another workspace. My credentials were all in another workspace folder, but when I fixed the path, it all worked like a charm on Version 22.1.3.202207240747 (installed via Homebrew Casks as dbeaver-community)

Comment: Saved my day, huge thanks! Works on 23.1.0.202306041918 for MacOS (12.6.3)

Comment: Now, decrypt key is stored at https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/blob/8ed6d430a12ddc065a8bb69ec11babb152462f15/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.registry/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/registry/BaseProjectImpl.java#L77

Comment: `cd ~/AppData/Roaming/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver` in windows git bash

Comment: This answer is the quickest solution. Test on DB 23.2.4. Thanks @Tatsh !

Comment: Just as a heads up, passwords must be converted from unicode.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Faster and safer.

Comment: This is the right answer, I appreciate the thing the other guy did, but I'm a bit apprehensive about sending my creds to a random website.

Comment: @Mike this was my thought exactly.  Sending your database creds to a stranger is a really bad idea!

Answer (score 78):

For DBeaver 6.1.3+ the creds are stored in a "json" file now with different encryption.

This seemed to do the job for me:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.*;

public class DecryptDbeaver {

  // from the DBeaver source 8/23/19 https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/blob/57cec8ddfdbbf311261ebd0c7f957fdcd80a085f/plugins/org.jkiss.dbeaver.model/src/org/jkiss/dbeaver/model/impl/app/DefaultSecureStorage.java#L31
  private static final byte[] LOCAL_KEY_CACHE = new byte[] { -70, -69, 74, -97, 119, 74, -72, 83, -55, 108, 45, 101, 61, -2, 84, 74 };

  static String decrypt(byte[] contents) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    try (InputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents)) {
      byte[] fileIv = new byte[16];
      byteStream.read(fileIv);
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      SecretKey aes = new SecretKeySpec(LOCAL_KEY_CACHE, "AES");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aes, new IvParameterSpec(fileIv));
      try (CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(byteStream, cipher)) {
        return inputStreamToString(cipherIn);
      }
    }
  }

  static String inputStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("syntax: param1: full path to your credentials-config.json file");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println(decrypt(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0]))));
  }

}
```

Pass it the path of your credentials-config.json file on local filesystem, for me it was

```
 Compile it
 $ javac DecryptDbeaver.java
 Now run it [adjusts the paths to target your credentials-config.json file]
 $ java DecryptDbeaver ~/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json
 Or if java 11+:
 $ java DecryptDbeaver.java ~/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json
```

It will output to the console the user+pass for connections.

`{"postgres-jdbc-some-id":{"#connection":{"user":"your_user_name","password":"your_password"...`

If you don't recognize which password goes to which DB based on username, you must cross link the id names it also outputs initially to the sibling `data-sources.json` file (which should already be present and unencrypted and contains database coordinates).

Comment: As before, here is the Python (3) version: https://gist.github.com/felipou/50b60309f99b70b1e28f6d22da5d8e61

Comment: A note for Linux Users, the file is found in <workspace>/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json

The Workspace directory can be found the preferences -> General -> Workspace. So for me it was: ~/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json

Comment: In one CLI, java can run java files now: `java DecryptDbeaver.java ~/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json `

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to re-encode the json please? The goal is to set-up the credentials via a script that fetches them from an external source.

Comment: On Windows the path is: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver\credentials-config.json`

Comment: @J4Y-M maybe could use openssl like in the other answers, but in reverse? :)

Answer (score 68):

For Windows users (Tested Version 7.3.4, also tested 22.2.3)

Press File > Export > DBeaver > Project

Change the name of the export file to .zip, and unzip

Download OpenSSL, and copy `\projects\General\.dbeaver\credentials-config.json` into the same folder as the bin directory of openssl

Then run:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in "credentials-config.json"
```

If you have WSL installed, this command can also be run from a Linux install with openssl available (`which openssl`) from any directory within the Linux install (Tested with Ubuntu on WSL2 copied file to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\me\dbeaver\credentials`).

It will output to the terminal as default, if you need it in a file add  `> chosen_filename.json` to the command.

Comment: happens nothing. Where I can find the result

Comment: Working for Ubuntu as well

Comment: confirmed working!

Comment: The Export is not needed, just decrypt from the "credentials-config.json" file (you can find it here: %appdata%\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\.dbeaver).

Comment: Worked using Git Bash's OpenSSL installation.

Comment: You don't need to install OpenSSL on Windows if you have GitBash. There is a version of OpenSSL in the install folder for GitBash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10

Comment: Working on Ubuntu WSL2, and for dbeaver 23.2.0 ! thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is the command to get the decrypted version of dbeaver credentials file on your desired destination path:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d \
-K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a \
-iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 \
-in {path for the encrypted credentials file} > \
{your desired destination file}
```

- {your desired destination file} e.g. `~/Desktop/dbeaver-credentials.json`

You'll find `dbeaver-credentials.json` file on Desktop. But this file will have list of only usernames & passwords with some connection stanza (like `mysql5-17be86ca5ea-294e2a427af47fc4`). No db or server names will be there. You've to find the connection against the object id.

---

For Ubuntu `snap` package `dbeaver-ce`,

- {path for the encrypted credentials file} = `~/snap/dbeaver-ce/current/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json`

Comment: awesome! that works

Answer (score 11):

For Linux OS users, run this in Terminal:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K babb4a9f774ab853c96c2d653dfe544a -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in "path_to/credentials-config.json" | dd bs=1 skip=16 2>/dev/null
```

Just replace the string "path_to/credentials-config.json" with your actual path to that file and you'll get something like this:

```
{"mysql8-17e009389a8-5fc414bd64e183f4":{"#connection":{"user":"root","password":"root"}},"mysql8-18099236fdf-3c3fc761c6fdde":{"#connection":{"user":"user.name","password":"your_secret_password"},"network/ssh_tunnel":{"user":"sql","jumpServer0.password":""}}}%
```

Answer (score 4):

if there is package declaration just compile
javac -d . SimpleStringEncrypter.java
it will put it in the correct directory structure under the current directory
Then you can give
java -cp . packagename.SimpleStringEncrypter and it will run.
Basic java.

Anyway this program is fantastic and saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this:

```
docker run -d -p 18080:8080 --name crack-dbeaver-password-18080 geekyouth/crack-dbeaver-password
```

https://github.com/geekyouth/crack-dbeaver-password

Answer (score -5):

***If you dont want all the saved connections***

Just remove the --\DBeaverData\workspace6\General folder from the file system
so that it can not ask any password again.
and the workspace data will be lost.

You will loose all the custom settings and preferences.

Comment: although it could be useful, this is unrelated to the original question