# HttpWebRequest Add SSL .Key-File to WebRequest

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

I need to make request to a secure server. In order to authenticate in postman, I send over a .cer and .key + password

[postman settings that work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raCkM.png)

But how can I add .key + password to a WebRequest in C#?

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("~/Cert/mykey-wru.key", "PASSWORD");
```

...doenst work...

Comment: HttpWebRequest is deprecated, use HttpClient instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is combinde with creating the suggestes .pfx file and adding the cert to the local machine store.

than i needed to read them from there in order to get a seure ssl connection

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
            {
                if (certificate.FriendlyName.Contains("mycert"))
                    request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2__ctor_System_String_System_String_) with `.pfx` certificate file.

create this file with openssl (you need `.key` and `.crt` files):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.crt
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757939/12970150) might be helpful for finding openssl

Comment: hmpf... i tried making and adding the .pfx with password and adding the .cre this works fine in postman agian, but not in c#, somethins is still missing there

Comment: @FastSchonBaconBacon What exception you have?

Comment: "Cannot create SSL/TSL connection..." is what i am getting now

Comment: @FastSchonBaconBacon, looks like there is a problem with trusting the server certificate. Can you really trust him? If yes, then we will TEMPORARILY ignore this problem:
httpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

But this is extremely unsafe. This is for testing purposes only. Be sure to remove this code afterwards.

Comment: @FastSchonBaconBacon, can you make the request in the browser? the postman has a setting to ignore certificate problems.

And did I understand correctly that at the moment when reading the certificate, an exception does not occur now?

Comment: i've added the code but i still get the error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Comment: ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

is also not working for me