# How to activate Managed HSM and configure encryption with customer-managed keys stored in Azure Key Vault Managed HSM using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure, hsm

I’m working on to create Azure Key Vault Managed HSM using terraform. For that I have followed [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module) documentation.

The above documentation contains the code for creating the HSM but not for the activation of managed HSM.

I want to provision and activate a managed HSM using Terraform. Is it possible or not through the terraform?

After Activate a managed HSM, I want to configure encryption with customer-managed keys stored in Azure Key Vault Managed HSM. For that I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-key-vault-hsm) documentation, but it contains the Azure CLI code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately , its not directly possible to ***activate the Managed HSM from Terraform*** . Currently , you can ***only provision it from terraform or ARM template*** but ***for activating it has to be done only from PowerShell and Azure CLI***. It is also the same while updating the storage account with customer managed key and assigning a key vault role assignment.

If you use `azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key`, then you will get the below error:

[image]

***Overall all HSM Key vault Operations needs to be performed on CLI or Powershell.***

So , For workaround you can use `local-exec` in terraform to directly run it without performing separate operations.

**Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "keyvaulthsm-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module" "example" {
  name                       = "testKVHsm"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name                   = "Standard_B1"
  purge_protection_enabled   = true
  soft_delete_retention_days = 90
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  admin_object_ids           = [data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id]

  tags = {
    Env = "Test"
  }
}

variable "KeyName" {
  default=["C:/<Path>/cert_0.key","C:/<Path>/cert_1.key","C:/<Path>/cert_2.key"]
}

variable "CertName" {
  default=["C:/<Path>/cert_0.cer","C:/<Path>/cert_1.cer","C:/<Path>/cert_2.cer"]
}

resource "null_resource" "OPENSSLCERT" {
    count = 3
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
     cd  "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
    ./openssl.exe req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout ${var.KeyName[count.index]}  -x509 -days 365 -out ${var.CertName[count.index]} -subj "/C=IN/ST=Telangana/L=Hyderabad/O=exy ltd/OU=Stack/CN=domain.onmicrosoft.com"
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell","-Command"
    ]
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "securityDomain" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az keyvault security-domain download --hsm-name ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name} --sd-wrapping-keys ./cert_0.cer ./cert_1.cer ./cert_2.cer --sd-quorum 2 --security-domain-file ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name}-SD.json
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell","-Command"
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.OPENSSLCERT
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "ansumanhsmstor1"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "roleassignkv" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az keyvault role assignment create --hsm-name ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name} --role "Managed HSM Crypto Service Encryption User" --assignee ${azurerm_storage_account.example.identity[0].principal_id} --scope /keys
    az keyvault role assignment create --hsm-name ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name} --role "Managed HSM Crypto User" --assignee ${data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id} --scope /
    az keyvault key create --hsm-name ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.name} --name storageencryptionkey --ops wrapKey unwrapKey --kty RSA-HSM --size 3072
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell","-Command"
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.securityDomain,
    azurerm_storage_account.example
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "storageupdate" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az storage account update --name ${azurerm_storage_account.example.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --encryption-key-name storageencryptionkey --encryption-key-source Microsoft.Keyvault --encryption-key-vault ${azurerm_key_vault_managed_hardware_security_module.example.hsm_uri}
    EOT
    interpreter = [
      "PowerShell","-Command"
    ]
  }
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.securityDomain,
    azurerm_storage_account.example,
    null_resource.roleassignkv
  ]
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** ***Please make sure to enable Purge Protection on the HSM Keyvault*** and have all the required permissions on [Management Plane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/secure-your-managed-hsm#example) (not added in code) and [Control Plane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-hsm/built-in-roles) (I have added in the code). To install OpenSSL you can refer this answer by **mtotowamkwe** on this ***[`SO thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10)***.

Comment: Thanks @AnsumanBal, I'm unable to find this `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
    ./openssl.exe` path in my local system. Is possible to store the certs in current terraform working folder?

Comment: I'm trying to generate certificates using openssl from this `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` location. But I'm getting this `req: can't open "cert_0_key" for writing, permission denied error in req` error

Comment: @Pradeep, For the second permission denied error you have to use elevated terminal to create the certs .. so If you are using VSCode then open it in admin mode.

Comment: Is it possible to use certificates created in Azure Key Vault for activating the HSM, instead of generating certificates in local machine?

Comment: @Pradeep, I have not tried that but I guess we can use as we can create RSA key pairs in keyvault . But for activation again you will have to download it and then reference it as there is no identity in HSM to directly reference it from keyvault.

Comment: AnsumanBal, Getting this `Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.storageupdate,
│   on main.tf line 93, in resource "null_resource" "storageupdate":
│   93:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command '    az storage account update --name xxxxx --resource-group xxx-KV-HSM-RG-xx --encryption-key-name storageencryptionkey --encryption-key-source
│ Microsoft.Keyvault --encryption-key-vault https://xxxxx.managedhsm.azure.net/
│ ': exit status 1. Output: ERROR: (KeyVaultPolicyError) Keyvault policy recoverable is not set` error.

Comment: @Pradeep, you have to create a purge enabled HSM keyvault . So keep purge_protection_enabled   = true as I have mentioned in note.

Comment: @Pradeep, I am doing the same as mine is a openssl server , that's why I am running cd  "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin" and then calling the openssl to create certs . And then in variables as you can see in answer I am calling paths which are same as my terraform project to save the certs.

Comment: AnsumanBal, I'm getting this `Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.storageupdate,
│
│ Error running command '    az storage account update --name xxxxxx --resource-group xxxx --encryption-key-name storageencryptionkey --encryption-key-source
│ Microsoft.Keyvault --encryption-key-vault https://xxxx.managedhsm.azure.net/
│ ': exit status 1. Output: ERROR: (KeyVaultAuthenticationFailure) The operation failed because of authentication issue on the keyvault. For more information, see -
│ https://aka.ms/storagekeyvaultaccesspolicy` error.