# how to solve openssl problem on windows 11 pro while working on symfony jwt authentication generating key pair

Tags: php, symfony

**openssl rsa -pubout -in app/var/jwt/private.pem -out app/var/jwt/public.pem**
*openssl : The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1*

- openssl rsa -pubout -in app/var/jwt/private.pem -out app/var/jwt/publ ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (openssl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: `openssl` syntax alont with `/` forwardslashes in your example suggest you are looking at a Linux path and the linux `openssl` , and you are trying to use that on Windows,which obviously does not work, and if the openssl exec is found your path would also be wrong... so I assume you are blindly copy-pasting from somewhere...  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10

Comment: it appears that you have not installed openssl , or it is not in the PATH environment variable of the Win OS

Comment: Installed and set environment variable also but problem remains same