# How to correctly setup TLS/SSL on localhost using http-server?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, localhost, httpserver

I'm using [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to serve my local project through HTTPS. To create the `key.pem` and the `cert.pem` files, I followed [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server):

> First, you need to make sure that `openssl` is installed correctly, and
> you have `key.pem` and `cert.pem` files. You can generate them using this
> command:
>
> ```
> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
> ```
>
> You will be prompted with a few questions after
> entering the command. Use `127.0.0.1` as value for "`Common name`" if you
> want to be able to install the certificate in your OS's root
> certificate store or browser so that it is trusted.
>
> This generates a cert-key pair and it will be valid for 3650 days
> (about 10 years).
>
> Then you need to run the server with `-S` for enabling SSL and `-C` for
> your certificate file.
>
> ```
> http-server -S -C cert.pem
> ```

I used the `openssl.exe` [come with the Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757939/3709765), and [installed the generated certificate on Windows](https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/ssl-certificates-installation/import-and-export-certificate-microsoft-windows) (onto the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" entry). Here is the output after running the server:

> ```
> Starting up http-server, serving ./ through https
>
> http-server version: 14.1.1
>
> http-server settings:
> CORS: disabled
> Cache: 3600 seconds
> Connection Timeout: 120 seconds
> Directory Listings: visible
> AutoIndex: visible
> Serve GZIP Files: false
> Serve Brotli Files: false
> Default File Extension: none
>
> Available on:
>   https://10.20.30.232:8080
>   https://192.168.56.1:8080 
>   https://192.168.1.126:8080
>   https://127.0.0.1:8080
> Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
> ```

But, when I access the `https://127.0.0.1:8080`, I'm encountered with the following error on Google Chrome:

> **Your connection is not private**
> ...
> `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`
> Subject: 127.0.0.1
> Issuer: 127.0.0.1
> ...
> This server could not prove that it is 127.0.0.1; its security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names.

And, the following is the error message Mozilla Firefox presents:

> 127.0.0.1:8080 uses an invalid security certificate.
> The certificate does not come from a trusted source.
> Error code: `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY`
>
> ```
> https://127.0.0.1:8080/
> The server uses a certificate with a basic constraints extension identifying it
> as a certificate authority. For a properly-issued certificate, this should not
> be the case.
> HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
> HTTP Public Key Pinning: false
> ```

So, what am I missing on setting up the HTTPS server to avoid the aforementioned errors?!

Answer (score 4):

Chrome should accept this certificate if you explicitly list 127.0.0.1 as a "Subject Alternative Name" (SAN) of type IP. You can do so by adding `-addext "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1"` to the openssl command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -addext "subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1"
```

Firefox complains about a very different issue, i.e. that a certificate with a basic constraints extension with `CA:TRUE` is being used as an end-entity certificate. See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1034124

You could try to generate the certificate without the basic constraints extenstion.

The shortcut solution would be to leverage existing solutions like https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert or https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert.

Comment: Thanks for the response; being explicit on expressing the "`SAN`" did resolve the issue with Google Chrome, you're awesome; but, in case of Firefox, could you please explain on how to _"generate the certificate without the basic constraints extension"_. I appreciate it.

Comment: If `basicConstraints` is defined in your `openssl.cnf`, comment it out. However, I'm not sure what implication this will have on the ability to install this certificate as a root certificate. If possible, I would go with the "shortcuts" just added to the solution.